# To print all alphabets (excluding digits) in a given line

Tags: bash, text-processing

I have one file

FILE 1:

```
Edward-201-singer
Andrew-James-404-writer
```

I want output as

```
Edward
Andrew-James
```

Comment: Dash isn’t a letter...?

Comment: So, you want all characters in a line, until you find a digit. And then exclude a `-` prior to that digit as well?

Comment: Please clarify your question. Your example doesn't match your requirements.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas :
Its like i want to print every thing in a given line until i find -[0-9] (any number)

Comment: Please edit your question to add that information.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want all characters in a line, until you find a digit. And then exclude an optional `-` prior to that digit as well:

```
sed 's/-\{0,1\}[[:digit:]].*//' your-file
```

<sup>(with  GNU `sed`, you can replace `\{0,1\}` with `\?`. Or `sed -E 's/-?[[:digit:]].*//'` with some).</sup>

This should handle your examples, although without more detail I can't say it would handle everything in your file.

If you want to change your file in-place, with some `sed` implementations, you can add a `-i.bak` to the sed command (backs up file to `your-file.bak`, makes changes to `your-file`) or add a `> new-file` on the end to write `new-file` with the results

Answer (score 1):

To remove everything from after the first digit preceded by a dash (and the dash-digit as well):

```
sed 's/-[0-9].*//' file
```

With the data given in the question in the file `file`, this generates

```
Edward
Andrew-James
```

Removing digits only (as asked in the title of the question) can be done with `tr -d '0-9' <file`, but would produce

```
Edward--singer
Andrew-James--writer
```

... which is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing anything else about the format, this works for the two values you've provided:

```
while read
do
    echo "${REPLY%-*-*}"
done < file1
```